# yii2 beginWidget -> unknown method

Tags: class, widget, yii2, active-form

In yii I had such code which was roking OK

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'ride-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>false,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
));
```

now I am trying to use it in Yii 2 version.
But I'm getting error

```
Calling unknown method: yii\web\View::beginWidget()
```

Why ? and what class maybe I should additionally use to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears because `yii\web\View` class simply does not have the method `beginWidget()`.

For working with forms in Yii2 use [ActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html) widget.

Replace your code with:

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;    

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'ride-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>false,
    'validateOnSubmit' => true, // this is redundant because it's true by default
]);

// ...

ActiveForm::end();
```

Answer (score 0):

2 things i would check for if a method is unknown.

1) is the class included before you call it?

2) Are you creating an instance of the class and calling the class from that instance variable?

```
include 'myClass.php';

$class = new myClassName();

$class->method();
```